# site on IIS of my Windows 7 error 404 after install WebMatrix and IIS Express

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-ce, orchardcms, webmatrix, iis-express

I use Orchard CMS (MVC 3), first install with SQLCE, add site to IIS and running fine.

Later, I install WebMatrix to migrate from SQLCE to SQL Express.

After that my site on default IIS can not run anymore (error 404). I can only run the site from WebMatrix (using IIS Express)

Please help me to solve this problem!

Thank in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Check your logs (App_data\logs). My guess would be that you got the credentials to the database wrong, or that you altogether forgot to add the ASP.NET app pool's user to the database logins and give it db_owner rights.